# Anchor tag does not work on jquery mobile label

Tags: android, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am using JQuery-mobile and i am unable to use below on actual phone.

```
<label for='check'>Enjoy your Search at <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','','width=530, height=580');">Google</a>
```

That is when the user is zoomed in and clicks on the link it does not execute the onclick java script.

The anchor tag is coming from a legacy system and hence i cannot change it due to support reasons.

Has anyone faced this kind of issue before and can someone help me solve this?

I managed to have a small jsfiddle for this.
http://jsfiddle.net/QsCSj/

Thanks,
Dhimil.

Comment: putting a link in a label associated to an input is very bad practice